# Trying If else condition in EVAL in imacros gives error

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, imacros

This is the [link](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&Locality=Kalyan&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=10-Lacs&BudgetMax=30-Lacs) from where I m extracting data

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:sLB&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET pqr {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:HIDDEN&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET abc {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:HIDDEN&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET def {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
PROMPT "{{abc}} BHK {{def}}"

SET VAR7 EVAL("if (\"{{!abc}}\" == ' ') PROMPT "{{abc}} {{def}}"; else \"PROMPT "{{abc}} BHK {{def}}\";")
PROMPT {{VAR7}}
```

Here I'm checking the condition if the value of the variable **abc** is null or blank, then print data of two variable i.e **abc** and **def** else print data of **abc** and **def** **concatenated with BHK in between the both**.
But this gives me error

```
MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 71 (Error code: -910)
```

Any suggestion where I'm going wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your question...

If variable `abc` is null or blank,
  then return `abc` and `def`  *(why bother returning abc if it's blank/null?)*
  else return `abc` + `"BHK"` + `def`

Since I don't really understand exactly what you're extracting even though you provided a link, I created a test case below with the answer:

```
'Set test values
SET abc "100"
SET def "Apartment"

'Evaluation below, will abc = ' '?
SET VAR7 EVAL("('{{abc}}'==' ')?\"{{abc}} {{def}}\" : \"{{abc}} BHK {{def}}\";")
'return results of evaluation
PROMPT {{VAR7}}

'test abc with blank value
SET abc " "
SET VAR7 EVAL("('{{abc}}'==' ')?\"{{abc}} {{def}}\" : \"{{abc}} BHK {{def}}\";")
'return results of evaluation
PROMPT {{VAR7}}
```

Remember, you can't use Javascript to control flow/logic for Imacros.  It looked like you were trying to create Imacro commands via javascript.  If this answer helped, please mark as such.  Thanks!